# Adding 500+ markers gets the app hanging

Tags: android, performance, google-maps

I am developing an app of places/shops and have 500+ markers from DB on a Google Map.

I add 2 kinds of places and one kind of shop like this:

```
    Cursor places = db.getAllPlaces();
    this.placeMarker0 = new ItemizedMarker(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.place0), this);
    this.placeMarker1 = new ItemizedMarker(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.place1), this);
    this.shopMarker = new ItemizedMarker(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.shop), this);
    if (places.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] coordinates = places.getString(11).split(",");
            if (coordinates.length > 0) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double
                        .parseDouble(coordinates[0]) * 1E6), (int) (Double
                        .parseDouble(coordinates[1]) * 1E6));
                OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, places
                        .getString(1), Integer.toString(places.getInt(0)));
                if (places.getInt(12) == 0) {
                    placeMarker0.addMarker(overlayitem);
                } else if (places.getInt(12) == 1) {
                    placeMarker1.addMarker(overlayitem);
                } else {
                    shopMarker.addMarker(overlayitem);
                }
            } else {
                Log.w("GMaps", "Place not located - " + places.getString(1));
            }
        } while (places.moveToNext());
        this.placeMarker0.populateNow();
        this.mapOverlays.add(placeMarker0);
        this.placeMarker1.populateNow();
        this.mapOverlays.add(placeMarker1);
        this.shopMarker.populateNow();
    }
```

This works just fine, and all markers are shown (not shops by default though:-) )

The problem is, that after adding all the markers, the app often freezes and you can't click any of the markers or pinch-zoom / move the map for a while. I have ZoomControls added, and they work, but not interacting with the map directly.

Is Android Google Map API just not good at handling many markers, or should I use another approach?

If you need more details, please let me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Marker Clusters](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html) instead of creating 500+ individual markers? In addition to the performance overhead, your current setup could overwhelm the user.

Comment: Seems like a cool library. Thanks! I'll try that out in the near future!